# Routing TLD in docker image to 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns, docker, tld, dnsmasq

Foreword

My rails app cares about the hostname. So for example when the request comes from `domain-a.dev` it behaves differently than when the request comes from `domain-b.dev`. I want to test this behaviour and therefore have routed the complete `*.dev` TLD to `127.0.0.1` on my local machine, so I can set the domain of the server in my tests to what I want but it always uses my local machine tests server.

This is necessary because my tests use `selenium`, which launches an external browser and browses to `domain-a.dev` or `domain-b.dev`. So I cannot simply overwrite `request.hostname` (or so) in my tests, because this has no effect on the external browser.

Now I want to use a docker image for my tests, so I do not have to configure the test environment on multiple servers but simply start the docker image. Everything works so far but the `*.dev` resolving.

---

AFAIK Docker uses the hosts nameserver or google nameserver by default (https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#dns), but that would mean to change the host's dns to accomplish my goal which I don't want.

I want to build a docker image, where a special TLD, for example `dev`, always routes to `127.0.0.1`, **without touching the docker host**.

This means that for everybody running this docker image, for example `domain.dev` will be resolved to `127.0.0.1` inside the container. (Not only `domain.dev`, but every `*.dev` domain.). Other TLDs should work as usual.

An idea I have is to start `dnsmasq` inside the container, configured to resolve `*.dev` to `127.0.0.1` and forward the rest to the usual nameserver. But I am new to docker and have no idea if this is too complicated or how this could be accomplished.

Another idea might be to overwrite `/etc/hosts` in the container with fixed entries for special domains. But this would mean I have to update the docker container in case I want to resolve new domains to `127.0.0.1`, which is a drawback if the domains change often.

What do the docker experts say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I basically worked around this now by using http://xip.io/

By using urls like `sub.127.0.0.1.xip.io` I can connect to my local machine. My app only has to know that `127.0.0.1.xip.io` is treated as the "top level domain", and `sub` is the domain name without tld. (In a Ruby on Rails app this can be done by adjusting `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 6` for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `docker run` to start your container, you have the `--add-host=""` argument which takes a hostname and an IP that get written to the container's `/etc/hosts`.

Your startup command would look like this:

```
docker run -d --add-host="domain-a.dev:192.168.0.10" [...]
```

Replace `192.168.0.10` with your computer's local IP address.

Don't use `127.0.0.1` as Docker will resolve that to the container not your computer.